# Choosing image for image well by open dialogue window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to choose a image with browsing window and put in image well.

here is my code, i can choose image but cannot see in image well, after choosing it should be appear in image well on window.

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender 
{
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];


    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];


    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {

        NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for( int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            NSImage *iconImage=[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
            [imageView setImage:iconImage];
        }
    }
}
```

In interface builder i have connected browse button with

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender;
```

and image well object with

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView* imageView;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithContentsOfFile` takes a file path. But `URLs` contains URLs. So you've got an impedance mismatch, and `iconImage` is coming up nil.

Use `initWithContentsOfURL` instead.

Also, why would you want to allow the user to select multiple images and then cycle through them all, setting the image view to show each of them in succession? (It is not going to show them all together; it can show only one image.) Just set the image view's `image` to the *first* (and only) image that the user selected.

Comment: By the way, you could have figured this out by using the debugger (or with NSLog). If you step through your code with the debugger (or insert NSLog statements) you can *see* that `iconImage` is coming up nil. You can pull your code completely apart in this way, making sure that *every line* is working as you expect. That way, you know exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: Oh, and don't set `setCanChooseDirectories` to YES. You want to the user to select files only. In fact, you should use `setAllowedFileTypes` to limit what the user can choose to image files. `[NSImage imageTypes]` gives you a list of the possible types.